# Why Mysql is not using indexes on join

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a query that joins table SPACES with 3 rows.
But MySql is not using indexes.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
environmen0_.description        AS col_0_0_,
environmen0_.fk_user_profile_id AS col_1_0_,
environmen0_.id                 AS col_2_0_,
environmen0_.ukey               AS col_3_0_,
environmen0_.environment_name   AS col_4_0_,
lifecycle5_.state               AS col_6_0_,
environmen0_.updated_date       AS col_7_0_,
environmen0_.updated_by         AS col_8_0_,
usersecuri1_.id                 AS id1_238_,
usersecuri1_.primary_entity     AS primary_2_238_,
space4_.alias_name               AS type_alias


FROM ENVIRONMENTS environmen0_ 
  STRAIGHT_JOIN SPACES space4_ 
              ON environmen0_.fk_space_id = space4_.id
  STRAIGHT_JOIN USER_SECURITY_PROFILES usersecuri1_
              ON environmen0_.fk_user_profile_id = usersecuri1_.id
  STRAIGHT_JOIN SECURITY_ROLE_PERMISSIONS permission2_
              ON usersecuri1_.id = permission2_.fk_profile_id

WHERE
      permission2_.permission_read = 1
 AND (permission2_.fk_security_role_id IN (2, 1))
 AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1
 AND 1 = 1
 AND (environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design'
   OR environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design')
 AND 1 = 1 AND 1 = 1
GROUP BY environmen0_.id
ORDER BY environmen0_.id ASC
LIMIT 25
```

How come that MySql refuses to use index? Join type is **ALL**, that problem leads that JOIN type for **ENVIRONMENTS** table will be **ALL**. If I remove from select this line

```
space4_.alias_name AS type_alias
```

Explain output
[image: explain output]

The output from CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `environments` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alias_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `ukey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namespace` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vstamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `builder_view` longtext,
  `environment_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `operation_scope` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_provision_profile_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_user_profile_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_mainApplication_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_organization_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_security_profile_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fk_space_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fk_state_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_environment_type` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ad600i5g7rewdxmuc1elmekdh` (`ukey`),
  KEY `FK_pxiie9k1gm297ejhr5y8k56a9` (`fk_provision_profile_id`),
  KEY `FK_35i1f8xibrr2apesdu9ahcpnt` (`fk_user_profile_id`),
  KEY `FK_b959faehk11qrxb06die67ukm` (`fk_mainApplication_id`),
  KEY `FK_554d71l9bovc8u804wghgyo38` (`fk_organization_id`),
  KEY `FK_bomv382tbq3rf4ae54ewkr8rs` (`fk_security_profile_id`),
  KEY `FK_9xype9ap7gcmdm5t077gdgor3` (`fk_space_id`),
  KEY `FK_th5888gw8704s2bfcw0r8hmr2` (`fk_state_id`),
  KEY `FK_aryfg8vfjdrhxrdxd3ykptsfq` (`fk_environment_type`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_35i1f8xibrr2apesdu9ahcpnt` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_user_profile_id`) REFERENCES `user_security_profiles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_554d71l9bovc8u804wghgyo38` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_organization_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9xype9ap7gcmdm5t077gdgor3` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_space_id`) REFERENCES `spaces` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_aryfg8vfjdrhxrdxd3ykptsfq` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_environment_type`) REFERENCES `environment_types` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_b959faehk11qrxb06die67ukm` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_mainApplication_id`) REFERENCES `services` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_bomv382tbq3rf4ae54ewkr8rs` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_security_profile_id`) REFERENCES `security_profiles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_pxiie9k1gm297ejhr5y8k56a9` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_provision_profile_id`) REFERENCES `provision_profiles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_th5888gw8704s2bfcw0r8hmr2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_state_id`) REFERENCES `lifecycles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3686 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**SHOW CREATE TABLE SPACES OUTPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE `spaces` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `alias_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `ukey` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `namespace` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vstamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registered` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `computeGroup_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_datacenter_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_environment_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_firewall_details_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_user_profile_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_infrastructure_space_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_network_details_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `networkGroup_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_organization_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_space_type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_state_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `storageGroup_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_sjlchubxlbvgi5ulks9wp9sde` (`ukey`),
  UNIQUE KEY `spaces_name_uindex` (`name`),
  KEY `FK_9nvkdrx0f46h75d6sa5oy6iwr` (`computeGroup_id`),
  KEY `FK_ejq2ibt89frkg86smcrmhyt5v` (`fk_datacenter_id`),
  KEY `FK_6ajs9lyo7mjmjjj4y3qjsc31g` (`fk_environment_type_id`),
  KEY `FK_7hm1q5w10wt88uxnhhgprxb` (`fk_firewall_details_id`),
  KEY `FK_bato9w3gb8niubughim3co8ep` (`fk_user_profile_id`),
  KEY `FK_ilpdrrgxshsrd3vfx3xtdfegx` (`fk_infrastructure_space_id`),
  KEY `FK_4lstxys6ovkiut13ja3r5rcpd` (`fk_network_details_id`),
  KEY `FK_n1633yw9h1jfv1wpa8hhtmafa` (`networkGroup_id`),
  KEY `FK_l9pbefokdexmg051uxucrue2i` (`fk_organization_id`),
  KEY `FK_gyvfscvcyyvwpxugo8sbcv7mc` (`fk_space_type_id`),
  KEY `FK_jjhvvr4g3v55iylkh54mee86d` (`fk_state_id`),
  KEY `FK_v4q19t54g2ecqslfdyit0gn7` (`storageGroup_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4lstxys6ovkiut13ja3r5rcpd` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_network_details_id`) REFERENCES `component_details` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_6ajs9lyo7mjmjjj4y3qjsc31g` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_environment_type_id`) REFERENCES `environment_types` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_7hm1q5w10wt88uxnhhgprxb` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_firewall_details_id`) REFERENCES `component_details` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_9nvkdrx0f46h75d6sa5oy6iwr` FOREIGN KEY (`computeGroup_id`) REFERENCES `compute_groups` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_bato9w3gb8niubughim3co8ep` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_user_profile_id`) REFERENCES `user_security_profiles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ejq2ibt89frkg86smcrmhyt5v` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_datacenter_id`) REFERENCES `data_centers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_gyvfscvcyyvwpxugo8sbcv7mc` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_space_type_id`) REFERENCES `space_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ilpdrrgxshsrd3vfx3xtdfegx` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_infrastructure_space_id`) REFERENCES `infrastructure_spaces` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_jjhvvr4g3v55iylkh54mee86d` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_state_id`) REFERENCES `lifecycles` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_l9pbefokdexmg051uxucrue2i` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_organization_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_n1633yw9h1jfv1wpa8hhtmafa` FOREIGN KEY (`networkGroup_id`) REFERENCES `network_groups` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_v4q19t54g2ecqslfdyit0gn7` FOREIGN KEY (`storageGroup_id`) REFERENCES `storage_groups` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**EXPLAIN  OUTPUT FORMAT JSON**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "5401.30"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "grouping_operation": {
        "using_temporary_table": true,
        "using_filesort": true,
        "nested_loop": [
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "environmen0_",
              "access_type": "ALL",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY",
                "UK_ad600i5g7rewdxmuc1elmekdh",
                "FK_pxiie9k1gm297ejhr5y8k56a9",
                "FK_35i1f8xibrr2apesdu9ahcpnt",
                "FK_b959faehk11qrxb06die67ukm",
                "FK_554d71l9bovc8u804wghgyo38",
                "FK_bomv382tbq3rf4ae54ewkr8rs",
                "FK_9xype9ap7gcmdm5t077gdgor3",
                "FK_th5888gw8704s2bfcw0r8hmr2",
                "FK_aryfg8vfjdrhxrdxd3ykptsfq"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 3026,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 574,
              "filtered": "19.00",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "3517.21",
                "eval_cost": "114.99",
                "prefix_cost": "3632.20",
                "data_read_per_join": "3M"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "description",
                "ukey",
                "updated_date",
                "updated_by",
                "environment_name",
                "operation_scope",
                "fk_user_profile_id",
                "fk_space_id"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(((`p3c`.`environmen0_`.`operation_scope` = 'design') or (`p3c`.`environmen0_`.`operation_scope` = 'design')) and ((`p3c`.`environmen0_`.`fk_user_profile_id` is not null) and (`p3c`.`environmen0_`.`fk_user_profile_id` is not null)))"
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "space4_",
              "access_type": "ALL",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 3,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 574,
              "filtered": "33.33",
              "using_join_buffer": "Block Nested Loop",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "1.27",
                "eval_cost": "114.99",
                "prefix_cost": "3978.44",
                "data_read_per_join": "3M"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "alias_name"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(`p3c`.`space4_`.`id` = `p3c`.`environmen0_`.`fk_space_id`)"
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "usersecuri1_",
              "access_type": "eq_ref",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY"
              ],
              "key": "PRIMARY",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "id"
              ],
              "key_length": "8",
              "ref": [
                "p3c.environmen0_.fk_user_profile_id"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 574,
              "filtered": "100.00",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "574.94",
                "eval_cost": "114.99",
                "prefix_cost": "4668.37",
                "data_read_per_join": "440K"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "primary_entity"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "permission2_",
              "access_type": "ref",
              "possible_keys": [
                "UK_6xoibydyrd0ygb48fin59dqpi",
                "FK_9aqihyu0wbjupml42sqqs6nj5"
              ],
              "key": "UK_6xoibydyrd0ygb48fin59dqpi",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "fk_profile_id"
              ],
              "key_length": "8",
              "ref": [
                "p3c.environmen0_.fk_user_profile_id"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 287,
              "filtered": "47.08",
              "index_condition": "(`p3c`.`permission2_`.`fk_security_role_id` in (2,1))",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "610.78",
                "eval_cost": "57.51",
                "prefix_cost": "5401.30",
                "data_read_per_join": "224K"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "permission_read",
                "fk_profile_id",
                "fk_security_role_id"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(`p3c`.`permission2_`.`permission_read` = 1)"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indexes for join table will be applied and ENVIRONMENT TABLE will not obtain all records. Could someone explain the behavior? What should I do in this case?

**MODIFIED QUERY, after all discussions**

Added indexes for Environment and SECURITY_ROLE_PERMISSIONS table, but performance is not changes

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
  environmen0_.description        AS col_0_0_,
  environmen0_.fk_user_profile_id AS col_1_0_,
  environmen0_.id                 AS col_2_0_,
  environmen0_.ukey               AS col_3_0_,
  environmen0_.environment_name   AS col_4_0_,
  environmen0_.updated_date       AS col_7_0_,
  environmen0_.updated_by         AS col_8_0_,
  usersecuri1_.id                 AS id1_238_,
  usersecuri1_.primary_entity     AS primary_2_238_,
  space4_.alias_name               AS type_alias


FROM ENVIRONMENTS environmen0_
  JOIN SPACES space4_  ON environmen0_.fk_space_id = space4_.id
  JOIN USER_SECURITY_PROFILES usersecuri1_ ON environmen0_.fk_user_profile_id = usersecuri1_.id
  JOIN SECURITY_ROLE_PERMISSIONS permission2_ ON usersecuri1_.id = permission2_.fk_profile_id
WHERE
      permission2_.permission_read = 1 AND (permission2_.fk_security_role_id IN (2, 1)) AND
      environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design'

GROUP BY environmen0_.id
ORDER BY environmen0_.id ASC
LIMIT 25
```

**The EXPLAIN JSON output for edited query**

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "7475.71"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "grouping_operation": {
        "using_temporary_table": true,
        "using_filesort": true,
        "cost_info": {
          "sort_cost": "1685.00"
        },
        "nested_loop": [
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "permission2_",
              "access_type": "index",
              "possible_keys": [
                "UK_6xoibydyrd0ygb48fin59dqpi",
                "FK_9aqihyu0wbjupml42sqqs6nj5",
                "security_index"
              ],
              "key": "security_index",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "fk_profile_id",
                "permission_read",
                "fk_security_role_id"
              ],
              "key_length": "18",
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 3579,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 1684,
              "filtered": "47.08",
              "using_index": true,
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "391.80",
                "eval_cost": "337.00",
                "prefix_cost": "728.80",
                "data_read_per_join": "1M"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "permission_read",
                "fk_profile_id",
                "fk_security_role_id"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "((`p3c`.`permission2_`.`permission_read` = 1) and (`p3c`.`permission2_`.`fk_security_role_id` in (2,1)))"
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "environmen0_",
              "access_type": "ref",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY",
                "UK_ad600i5g7rewdxmuc1elmekdh",
                "FK_pxiie9k1gm297ejhr5y8k56a9",
                "FK_35i1f8xibrr2apesdu9ahcpnt",
                "FK_b959faehk11qrxb06die67ukm",
                "FK_554d71l9bovc8u804wghgyo38",
                "FK_bomv382tbq3rf4ae54ewkr8rs",
                "FK_9xype9ap7gcmdm5t077gdgor3",
                "FK_th5888gw8704s2bfcw0r8hmr2",
                "FK_aryfg8vfjdrhxrdxd3ykptsfq",
                "environments_operation_scope_id_index"
              ],
              "key": "FK_35i1f8xibrr2apesdu9ahcpnt",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "fk_user_profile_id"
              ],
              "key_length": "9",
              "ref": [
                "p3c.permission2_.fk_profile_id"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 1684,
              "filtered": "100.00",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "1685.00",
                "eval_cost": "337.00",
                "prefix_cost": "2750.80",
                "data_read_per_join": "10M"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "description",
                "ukey",
                "updated_date",
                "updated_by",
                "environment_name",
                "operation_scope",
                "fk_user_profile_id",
                "fk_space_id"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(`p3c`.`environmen0_`.`operation_scope` = 'design')"
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "usersecuri1_",
              "access_type": "eq_ref",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY"
              ],
              "key": "PRIMARY",
              "used_key_parts": [
                "id"
              ],
              "key_length": "8",
              "ref": [
                "p3c.permission2_.fk_profile_id"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 1684,
              "filtered": "100.00",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "1685.00",
                "eval_cost": "337.00",
                "prefix_cost": "4772.80",
                "data_read_per_join": "1M"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "primary_entity"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "table": {
              "table_name": "space4_",
              "access_type": "ALL",
              "possible_keys": [
                "PRIMARY"
              ],
              "rows_examined_per_scan": 3,
              "rows_produced_per_join": 1685,
              "filtered": "33.33",
              "using_join_buffer": "Block Nested Loop",
              "cost_info": {
                "read_cost": "6.91",
                "eval_cost": "337.00",
                "prefix_cost": "5790.71",
                "data_read_per_join": "8M"
              },
              "used_columns": [
                "id",
                "alias_name"
              ],
              "attached_condition": "(`p3c`.`space4_`.`id` = `p3c`.`environmen0_`.`fk_space_id`)"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of `STRAIGHT_JOIN`

Get rid of `AND 1=1`

Don't `OR` together identical clauses, just say it once:

AND (environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design'
   OR environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design')

Indexes needed:

```
environmen0_:  INDEX(operation_scope, id)
permission2_:  INDEX(fk_profile_id, permission_read, fk_security_role_id)
```

When a table has only 3 rows, it does not matter if it uses an index.  As the table grows, or the parameters change, the Optimizer may pick a different index to use.

Comment: My Environment table has 3000 rows, and table SPACES has 3 rows, but indexes and not used. I've added explain output and out from CREATE TABLE

Comment: `environmen0_` can't use any of your indexes; it needs mine.  The other table is too tiny (3 rows) to draw any useful conclusions.

Comment: If table is tiny it cannot use index for join? If I remove the last select field, MySQL starts using indexes. Why it cannot use fk_spaceid?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE SPACES` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...;`

Comment: I added the required info, also added indexes as you proposed. Explain output show me the same output, For environment0_ access type is ALL, and access type for space4 is ALL. I have no idea why it's happening. But when I delete SELECT space4_.alias_name               AS type_alias, everything goes ok

Comment: What exactly is it happening? You are limiting the optimizer's choices with all these `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: I mean why MySql decided to use access type ALL for Environment table and for SPACE table, why would not Mysql use indexes?!

Comment: The database will only use an index if it makes sense to do so. For a table with only three rows, a full scan is almost always quicker.

Comment: That leads to the problem that related table (ENVIRONMENT) will be obtained with full scan (join type - ALL)

Comment: Well, now the Optimizer decided to start with `permissions2_`; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Apparently, it did not have the optimal `INDEX(permission_read, fk_security_role_id)`.  For _starting_ with this table, this is the order needed (unlike my first suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Rick James answer

1. what is it STRAIGHT_JOIN?:

> STRAIGHT_JOIN is similar to JOIN, except that the left table is always
>   read before the right table. This can be used for those (few) cases
>   for which the join optimizer puts the tables in the wrong order.

So, before use index for fk_space_id, MySQL will read ENVIRONMENTS first
and there You have only 1 filter condition:

```
AND (environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design'
   OR environmen0_.operation_scope = 'design')
```

operation_scope - not indexed ... mean == FULL SCAN

2. 1=1 - remove it all, it a DUMMY condition and do nothing in Your
   query
3. If You change STRAIGHT_JOIN to the normal JOIN, MySQL could or
   couldn't change reading order. If it decide change it - Your
   expected index start work. Choose or not - depends from many unclean
   parameters,

based on all of this - create index for (operation_scope, id) - will be
    best choice

Comment: I applied you changes, but it gives we the same output from EXPLAIN, access type for environment is ALL, and access type for space is ALL. It Selects 3026 * 3 rows. I'd like to reduce them. tnx

Comment: Hi @VitaliiKravchenko, from  plans - it different, may be same speed, but this could depend from data. If interesting - send all tables from query structure and datasets for tests. about 3 rows - all comments above correct, no reason for use index, about other tables need to check why.